# Sitecore 7.5 Css and Javascript Issue

Tags: sitecore

I have a problem with CSS/JS rendering after I upgraded Sitecore to version 7.5
The problem only occurs in a few areas in the Sitecore UI, for example when I want publish I cannot see the languages(they are hidden) or in the package designer (cannot see add item statically).
I can temporarily fix the problem by using Firebug to change the position of the two classes from absolute to relative but sometimes I can't submit button on click.

I don't know if somebody has had the same problem after upgrading Sitecore.

Note : the update is done successfully with no errors.
I checked the default.css and it has been modified after update.

Please help me with this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Did you clear your caches/force refresh/try incognito mode/another browser? It may be a caching issue of JS and CSS files from your previous version of Sitecore.

Comment: yes I clean all caches and delete all temp files, I restart the windows server ,no result always same problem.

Comment: I have to change the position for the CSS class scStretch and scWizardFormContentForOldIE scFlexContentWithoutFlexie
To relative or fixed attribute to see the content

Comment: what browser are you seeing this in? have you tried different browsers?

Comment: i tried firefox chrome IE and safari , all have same problem

Comment: you know for exemple i want to add new user i cannot see the rules or permissions the class the content in the popup is hidden

Comment: You should try using a clean instance of Sitecore 7.5 and see if you are able to replicate. It sounds like an issue with your upgrade, a missing CS/JS file maybe.

Comment: Exacty i think this is the problem, I did the upgrade many times from 6.5 till 7.5 and always same problem, I ll try to install a clean instance like you said and I ll compare to find which files are missing. Thank you

Comment: The only solution i found it its :
1- change the css class .scStretchAbsolute in Default.css and add height: 100% 
2- change the css class .scFlexContentWithoutFlexie in flex.css add Height :100%